# Snake Game using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

please am trying to get my snake head and body to connect for a while now.  i have created a function for the original snake and another function for the body. i used a list to grow the body using the original x and y position of the original position but i am missing the link to get the head to move the whole body, please can anyone give me some ideas?

The Goal of the game is to keep the snake alive without hitting the borders or crashing into itself.
My version of the snake game is with a maze obstacle and a background picture

File: snake_game.py

```
"""
File: snake_game.py
----------------
The Goal of the game is to keep the snake alive without hitting the borders or crashing into itself.
My version of the snake game is with a maze obstacle and a background picture
"""

import pygame
import random
import math
from simpleimage import SimpleImage

# Importing Image module from PIL package

from PIL import Image

N_ROWS = 6
N_COLS = 6
PATCH_SIZE = 111
WIDTH = N_COLS * PATCH_SIZE
HEIGHT = N_ROWS * PATCH_SIZE

PATCH_NAME = 'images/simba-sq1.jpg'
SCREEN_WIDTH = 600      # Width of screen in pixels
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600     # Height of screen in pixels

SNAKE_SIZE = 25


# pass parameters for new coordinates
def draw_snake(screen, x, y):
    radius = 8
    color = 40, 113, 68

    # tried doing a rounded snake lol decided to work with this
    inside_rec = pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [x, y, SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_SIZE])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, inside_rec, radius)

    # draw eyes
    radius = 4  # size
    circle_middle = (x + 20, y + 5)
    circle_middle2 = (x + 5, y + 5)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (254, 220, 0), circle_middle, radius)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (254, 220, 0), circle_middle2, radius)


def draw_snake_food(screen, x, y):
    snake_food_img = pygame.image.load('images/frog.png')
    screen.blit(snake_food_img, (x, y))


# using the distance formula to calculate how close both objects are
# D = Square root(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 -y1)^2
def ate_food(snake_x, snake_y, snake_food_x, snake_food_y):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(snake_x - snake_food_x, 2) +
                         (math.pow(snake_y - snake_food_y, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def draw_new_body(screen, snake_list):
    color = 40, 113, 68
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [x[0], x[1], SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_SIZE])

# def our_snake(screen, snake_block, snake_list):
#     for x in snake_list:
#         color = 40, 113, 68
#         pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])


def place_patch(row, col, patch, final_image):
    for y in range(patch.height):
        for x in range(patch.width):
            pixel = patch.get_pixel(x, y)
            final_image.set_pixel(x, y, pixel)
            final_image.set_pixel(x + PATCH_SIZE * col, y + PATCH_SIZE * row, pixel)
    return final_image


def make_recolored_patch(red_scale, green_scale, blue_scale):
    """
    Implement this function to make a patch for the Warhol Filter. It
    loads the patch image and recolors it.
    :param red_scale: A number to multiply each pixels' red component by
    :param green_scale: A number to multiply each pixels' green component by
    :param blue_scale: A number to multiply each pixels' blue component by
    :return: the newly generated patch
    """
    patch = SimpleImage(PATCH_NAME)
    for pixel in patch:
        pixel.red *= red_scale
        pixel.green *= green_scale
        pixel.blue *= blue_scale
    # TODO: your code here.
    return patch


def show_score(screen, score, x, y):
    # font for text font name and size (www.dafint.com) for more fonts
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
    score = font.render("Score : " + str(score), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))


def main():

    # Background Image
    image = SimpleImage(PATCH_NAME)
    # image.show()
    final_image = SimpleImage.blank(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    # TODO: your code here.
    # This is an example which should generate a pinkish patch
    for row in range(N_ROWS):
        for col in range(N_COLS):
            # The uniform() method returns a random floating number between the two specified numbers (both included).
            patch = make_recolored_patch(random.uniform(0, 0.5), random.uniform(0, 0.5), random.uniform(0, 0.5))
            place_patch(row, col, patch, final_image)
    # final_image.show()

    final_image.pil_image.save("images/newkarel.png")

    background_img = pygame.image.load('images/newkarel.png')

    # initialise pygame to access methods and functions
    # needed to run pygame
    pygame.init()

    # Create the window of the game
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    # Set Title, Icon and Background
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game by Bridget")
    icon = pygame.image.load('images/snake.jpg')
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

    # Snake
    snake_x = 300
    snake_y = 480
    change_snake_x = 0
    change_snake_y = 0

    snake_block = 10

    # snakex = x - 30
    # snakey = y
    previous_x = snake_x
    previous_y = snake_y

    new_pos_x = 0
    new_pos_y = 0

    snake_food_x = random.randint(0, 536)
    snake_food_y = random.randint(50, 150)

    # score board
    score = 0

    game_running = True

    direction = "up"

    text_x = 10
    text_y = 10

    snake_list = []
    length_of_snake = 0

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while game_running:
        # fill the background (R,G,B)
        screen.fill((10, 46, 54))

        # below the screen.fill so the image is infront.
        # loading of image in while loop slow downs the process
        screen.blit(background_img, (0, 0))

        # gets and checks all events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_running = False

            # if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    change_snake_x = -5
                    direction = "left"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    change_snake_x = 5
                    direction = "right"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    change_snake_y = -5
                    direction = "up"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    direction = "down"
                    change_snake_y = 5

            # stop moving if player releases key
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or \
                        event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    change_snake_x = 0
                    change_snake_y = 0

        # Update Movement of Snake
        snake_x += change_snake_x
        snake_y += change_snake_y

        # ToDo Fix the extra issue with the wall

        # sets wall boundaries for all coners
        if snake_x <= 0 + 4:
            # left wall
            change_snake_x = 0 + 4

        elif snake_x >= SCREEN_WIDTH - SNAKE_SIZE - 10:
            # right wall
            change_snake_x = SCREEN_WIDTH - SNAKE_SIZE - 10
        elif snake_y <= 0 + 4:
            # top wall
            change_snake_y = 0 + 4
        elif snake_y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - SNAKE_SIZE - 10:
            # bottom wall
            change_snake_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - SNAKE_SIZE - 10

        # check to see the distance between the food and snake
        if ate_food(snake_x, snake_y, snake_food_x, snake_food_y):
            score += 1

            length_of_snake += 1

            for i in range(length_of_snake):
                if i == 0:
                    previous_x = snake_x - (SNAKE_SIZE * i)
                    previous_y = snake_y
                if direction == "left":
                    previous_x = snake_x + (SNAKE_SIZE * i)
                    previous_y = snake_y
                elif direction == "right":
                    previous_x = snake_x - (SNAKE_SIZE * i)
                    previous_y = snake_y
                elif direction == "up":
                    previous_x = snake_x
                    previous_y = snake_y + (SNAKE_SIZE * i)
                elif direction == "down":
                    previous_x = snake_x
                    previous_y = snake_y - (SNAKE_SIZE * i)

                # add to body part
                snake_body = []
                snake_body.append(previous_x)
                snake_body.append(previous_y)
                snake_list.append(snake_body)

            # To keep randomly change food position
            snake_food_x = random.randint(0, 536)
            snake_food_y = random.randint(50, 450)

        draw_new_body(screen, snake_list)

        # add snake to background
        draw_snake(screen, snake_x, snake_y)
        # print(snake_x, snake_y)
        # add snake food to background
        draw_snake_food(screen, snake_food_x, snake_food_y)

        # add  Score Board
        show_score(screen, score, text_x, text_y)

        # update game
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please try to cut the code down to the part that you think is relevant to the problem, and fix the indentation in your posting so that it appears the same here as in your source file.

Comment: to change size you have to change `length_of_snake` when you eat food but you never change it.

Comment: when you edit question there is special button `{}` to format code. Use it.